# Cut specific frequencies of entire song, using a sample to select the frequencies to be remove

Tags: python, numpy, fft, frequency, librosa

I am trying with Numpy and Librosa to cut some specific frequencies from a song by using a sample made from a window of this song.
**Explanations** : I have a 4:30 minute song, I select a 2.667 seconds sample in this song, and I want to remove the frequencies that appear in this sample.

After importing my song, I encounter a problem to remove the special frequencies in my song : the length of my sample is smaller than the length of my entire song, so I cannot subtract the frequencies of my sample from my song (which I think can be a good method to remove the frequencies).

Do you have an idea of how can I proceed ?
Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa.display           

# song importation
y, sr = librosa.load("my_song.wav")                            # y: audio time series, sr: sampling rate

# creation of a sample
song_duration = librosa.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr)               # duration of song in seconds
sample_start = 0.384                                           # start of the sample (in seconds) here: 0.384
sample_end = 3.051                                             # end   of the sample (in seconds) here: 3.051
sample_duration = sample_end - sample_start                    # sample duration in seconds
position_start = int((sample_start*len(y))/song_duration)                     # the starting position of the sample
position_end = position_start + int((sample_duration*len(y))/song_duration)   # the end of the sample
sample = y[position_start:position_end]                        # the sample (fraction of y)
scaled = np.int16(sample/np.max(np.abs(sample)) * sr)          # need to scale to have integer and not float

fft_y = np.fft.fft(y)                                          # 1D discrete Fourier Transform of entire song
fft_sample = np.fft.fft(sample)                                # 1D discrete Fourier Transform of the sample
n_y = y.size
n_sample = sample.size
time_step = 1/sr
freq_y = np.fft.fftfreq(n_y, time_step)                        # Discrete Fourier Transform frequencies of entire song
freq_sample = np.fft.fftfreq(n_sample, time_step)              # Discrete Fourier Transform frequencies of sample

print("y length: {0}, fft_y length: {1}, fft_sample length {2}".format(len(y), len(fft_y), len(fft_sample)))
# returns: y length: 6431544, fft_y length: 6431544, fft_sample length 58807

print("freq_y length: {0}, freq_sample length: {1}".format(len(freq_y), len(freq_sample)))
# returns: freq_y length: 6431544, freq_sample length: 58807
```

Maybe I didn't do something right, or it is my approach that is not good.
Thank you for your attention and sorry if I made mistakes in English!

Comment: Are you trying to do noise reduction? Or trying to eliminate one sound source (ex instrument) in your track?

Comment: I am trying to eliminate one sound source in my track (ex : a guitar in a song).

Comment: Do you have access to the guitar track alone? (can simplify problem). What else is in the track but guitar?

Comment: I can have access to the guitar track alone. In the track I can have many samples (a beat, a bass, some synth, etc). For example, the song Aerodynamic by Daft Punk has many samples. If it's too hard, I can start with simpler song.

Answer (score 2):

To separate out different sound sources from a mixture is called Source Separation. If you don't have detailed information about the sources, it is known as **Blind Source Separation**. It is a challenging problem in general, and widely researched. A simple method you can try is FastICA:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html

Music can be particularly challenging because such a process often gives small artifacts. You may need to edit those away later.